# Responsive menu opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, responsive

I seem to have a problem with my responsive menu.
I have to start by saying that I'm not a programmer, I know very little code but, unfortunately, I have been assiged to some web design tasks at work anyway.

My problem is: website is not entirely responsive, but the "articles" section is. Under 600px the menu bar is replaced by a hamburger menu.
Weird thing: When clicking on a section on the hambuger menu, instead of opening the wesite full page it opens the menu in the space occupied by the menu, keeping the article below.
Weird thing #2: despite starting from a template (so they should be all the same), it does that only in some pages, while others work properly.

[Example of page working](http://www.fidia.it/articoli/16_11/intervista_fontana.html)

[Example of page not working](http://www.fidia.it/articoli/17_02/filiali_fidia.html)

I honestly have no idea what's wrong.

P.s. I haven't made the website, I just work on it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see, [**How to Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: (ok, no idea why the title was cropped)

Comment: I'm actually on mobile, can't see much... If I where you, I'll begin by looking at the header of a working page and a no working one, and compare their `html` and the related CSS/JS

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters these two pages are not using the same template.  You can [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEIme.png) that the page that "doesn't work" has the menu being loaded in via iframe.  You can "fix" the odd behaviour by either changing the articles to use the same non-iframing template or you can add `target="_top"` to your menu links in /articoli/menu_mobile.html.

I recommend the consistency of using one non-iframing template, but adding the target is probably faster and easier.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! Unfortunately I did not make the original structure, so I have to work around the mistakes. The website will be upgraded to a newer, wordpress powered version in a couple of months so they asked to just fix the minimum necessary. Thank you!